# The NuGet restore task of my CI on custom Azure Pipelines Agent pool looks in NuGetFallbackFolder

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines

My CI works fine on Azure Pipelines Hosted Agent.
I need to use my own agent on a VM.
When I run the CI on that custom agent, the `Nuget restore` task fails:

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.Threading.4.3.0' from source 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'.
```

There is a `Nuget.Config` file `%appdata%/Roaming/Nuget`, I added one in  `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config` and also on my solution folder. I restarted the agent after adding these files.
Yet, the problem remains.

Comment: perhaps `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.threading\4.3.0` was not extracted correctly. You could try deleting it and NuGet will restore the package from nuget.org into your global packages folder if needed. Or you could delete the whole NuGetFalllbackFolder and the dotnet cli should re-create it on the next run.

Comment: I deleted the content of the folder and not only the CI went through but the folder emained empty. If you could explain the role of that folder in an answer I'd mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The NuGet restore task of my CI on custom Azure Pipelines Agent pool looks in NuGetFallbackFolder

Just as indicated in the error log:

> **An error occurred while retrieving package metadata** for
>   'System.Threading.4.3.0' from source 'C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'

That means NuGet not get the correct package metadata from that source. Most of the reason for this error is that the package was broken for some reason. We just need delete that package/folder and let nuget restore it from nuget.org.

The `NuGetFallbackFolder` contains a set of Nuget packages that the SDK expects to use. It's used as a nuget source whenever dotnet is trying to resolve nuget packages. Removing is generally similar to removing your nuget cache: .NET Core will simply not find the packages and download them into the (normal, non-NuGetFallbackFolder) local nuget cache.

You can get those info from natemcmaster`s answer:

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/237#issuecomment-413767900

> you can safely delete this folder. NuGet will download what you need.
>   You are likely to find, however, that this will just shift content
>   from the NuGetFallbackFolder to %USERPROFILE%/.nuget/packages.

Hope this helps.